# how to create an application like youtube with miniplayer

Tags: android, youtube

[image]

Any ideas how we can make a float activity like the mini player that Google has implemented in their YouTube app?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `ViewDragHelper` with `Service`. Check [this](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/) for creating dragView like youtube. You will get some idea from it.

Comment: this link is showing error 404. can you please update the link if possible?

Answer (score 0):

You may set your Activity's window to be floating. You can do this either by giving your activity the Dialog style defined by Android (android:style/Theme.Dialog), or define your own style, like this:

```
<style name="MiniWindow">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Explore more!